# Extract text from the complex string

Tags: javascript, regex

My string contains

`str = "Its a test string @[test_u](89) and @[test_v](91), lets try it."`

And I am extracting

`usernames = str.match(/([^"@\[])[^@\[]+?(?=\]\([1-9]+[0-9]*\))+/g); // ["test_u","test_v"]`

And I need to extract id's in similar way and need `["89", "91"]`

I have incomplete regex as `ids = str.match(/([^"(])[^@\(]+?(?=\))+/g);`

Please suggest regex for extracting id's.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may extract them with the use of capturing groups:

```js
var rx = /@\[([^\][]+)]\((\d+)\)/g;
var s = "Its a test string @[test_u](89) and @[test_v](91), lets try it."
var keys=[],ids=[], m;
while (m = rx.exec(s)) {
  keys.push(m[1]);
  ids.push(m[2]);
}
console.log(keys);
console.log(ids)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yu79U0/1). It matches:

- `@\[` - a `@[` char sequence
- `([^\][]+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than `]` and `[`
- `]\(` - a `](` substring
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `\)` - a `)` char.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor Stribiżew